# Selenium - Page Wait for Angular using Protractor javascript code

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I am testing a angularjs page and using selenium(java) to write automation scripts for the same.

The following is the code that I use for the page synchronization wait before proceeding to next screen action

```
public static boolean angularHasFinishedProcessing() {
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pageLoadCondition = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            driver = GetDriver();//This is to get the driver in current action.
            String hasAngularFinishedScript = "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];\n" +
                    "var el = document.querySelector('html');\n" +
                    "if (!window.angular) {\n" +
                     "console.log('1'); \n" +
                    "    callback('false')\n" +
                    "}\n" +
                    "if (angular.getTestability) {\n" +
                    "    angular.getTestability(el).whenStable(function(){callback('true')});\n" +
                    "} else {\n" +
                    "console.log('hello3'); \n" +
                    "    if (!angular.element(el).injector()) {\n" +
                    "        callback('false')\n" +
                    "    }\n" +
                    "    var browser = angular.element(el).injector().get('$browser');\n" +
                    "    browser.notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(function(){callback('true')});\n" +
                    "}";

            JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            String isProcessingFinished = javascriptExecutor.executeAsyncScript(hasAngularFinishedScript).toString();

            return Boolean.valueOf(isProcessingFinished);
        }
    };

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    boolean bRet = (wait.until(pageLoadCondition));
    if (bRet) {
        return bRet;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

The issue is isProcessingFinished is always false, the console always writes 1 (meaning window.angular always returns false).

Also, Since,  there is no way I can debug the javascript snippet during the execution, I don't know if there is any other issue. Could someone help please?

Comment: You could use a conditional statement for the doubtful code and protractor screenshot functionality instead of loging the errors

Comment: Selenium is too low level library, so you should use some wrappers of it. Take a look at http://selenide.org/, there you can use smart waits and it will solve all your problems

Comment: Is the variable `window.angular` present when you check it in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** For how to debug javascript

Add a breakpoint before this wait function, run script until stopped at this breakpoint, Open DevTool of browser and execute `window.angular` in console Tab to see it's true or false.

And you can continue to execute the rest code lines of your javascript snippet in console Tab to examine any code issue or work as expect.